# Email Duplicates in All Subscriber list with different SubscriberKey

Tags: marketing-cloud, soql, findduplicates

I have different duplicates email contacts with different SubscriberKey.

I performed this query :

```sql
SELECT * FROM _ListSubscribers a WHERE a.EmailAddress IN
(SELECT a.EmailAddress FROM _ListSubscribers a 
GROUP BY a.EmailAddress 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
```

But I have all the different lines with the contacts. I can see that sometimes, a contact exists 4 times with the same email and different Subkey.

How can I adapt my query to select only the oldest contacts and exclude the most recent created date ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using lists, you'll see lots of duplication. There's a row for every instance of a subscriber in each list they're members of. To your point:

```sql
SELECT
    x.*
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY s.EmailAddress ORDER BY s.DateJoined ASC) AS RowNumber,
            s.*
        FROM _Subscribers s WITH (NOLOCK)
    ) AS x
WHERE
    x.RowNumber = 1
```

Forget the "WITH (NOLOCK)" clause, if you like. Test it, if you have a busy account. Decide for yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot it is working :))